# how to open map activity on image clicked?

Tags: android

i have created a map activity. and i call map activty on button clicked. but it shows error. here is my code: 
`map_icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent i = new Intent(DepartmentUpdate_Detail.this,
     MapActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("lat", lat);
    i.putExtra("lng", lng);
    startActivity(i);
     }
     });`
```

`

//and my map Activity is below:

public class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener {

```
private GoogleMap map;

private int zoomLevel = 7;

String latitude,longitude,address,city,country;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {   
        latitude = extras.getString("lat");
        longitude = extras.getString("lng");

    }   
    LatLng defaultLatLng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latitude), Double.valueOf(longitude));
    //Log.e("Latitude:Longitude",":"+Double.valueOf(latitude)+":"+ Double.valueOf(longitude));

     Geocoder geocoder;
         List<Address> addresses;
         geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
         try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.valueOf(latitude), Double.valueOf(longitude), 1);
          address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
          city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
          country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (map!=null){

            map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            map.setTrafficEnabled(true);

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Move the camera instantly to defaultLatLng.

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(defaultLatLng, zoomLevel));

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(defaultLatLng)

                    .title("Location:")

                    .snippet(address+", "+city+", "+country)

                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        }

    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override

public void onPause() {

    if (map != null){
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override

public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aks, where did you declare the onClickListener? It should be declared in the onCreate() method so that as soon as the activity is inflated the clickListener is available to listen.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your data in Uri.parse and this code inside onClick method

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia&mode=b");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```